# distribution for the expected value of the mean

Tags: distributions, beta-distribution

May I know if there is a distribution for the expected value of the mean of beta variables?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are trying to ask?  A Beta variable has a mean, which is a *number,* so it is useless to think of that as having a distribution.  Would you perhaps be referring to the mean of a sample of independent identically distributed Beta variables?

Comment: May I know is it easy to verify analytically whether an estimator that contains the sum of beta variables is biased or not biased in a finite case?

Comment: "Easy" depends on your math skills, on the specific estimator ("contains the sum" is not sufficiently specific), and (perhaps) on the parameters of those variables.  Why not give us those details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not at all sure about this, but I think that if you take the mean of beta variables that are independent but not necessarily identically distributed, the resulting mean approaches a random variable normally distributed as the number of averaged variables increases (because of  [Lyapunov central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Lyapunov_CLT)). Is that right?

An empirical test seems to confirm this. Here's the distribution of 10000 means, each coming from 100 betas with shape1 = 1 and varying shape2.

```
set.seed(1234)
means <- rep(NA, 10000)
for(i in 1:length(means)) {
    means[i] <- mean(rbeta(n= 100, shape1= 1, shape2= seq(0.1, 10, length.out= 100)))
}
qqnorm(means)
```

[image]